# Программа работает из IDE, но не из .jar

Tags: java

Всем привет. Очень прошу вашей помощи.
Написал простейшую программу, которая пересылает через сокет серверу побайтно строку и\или файл.
Клиент работает при дебагинге, т.е. компьютер сам себе это всё отсылает успешно. 
Клиент верно отсылает данные, будучи запущенным из IDE (IntelliJ IDEA), серверу на другом компьютере.
Стоит сотворить .jar и запустить его - присылает размер строки и сервак показывает Connection Reset.

Я не уверен, что нужен код клиента или сервера, т.к. ошибка явно не в нём, ибо из ИДЕ он работает. Если нужны какие-либо данные, с радостью предоставлю.

UPD1 Пожелали код - прикрепляю код.  (=
UPD2 Как билдю: File - Project Structure - Artifacts. Жму на плюсик, выбираю JAR. Ввожу имя, папку, где создаст джарник, галочка в Build on make. В манифест файл указываю \ИмяПроекта\src\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF
Показываю ему Main class. Во вкладке Output layout перетаскиваю ИмяПроекта compile output в ИмяПроекта.jar (налево). Жму "Ок". 
Build - Make project. Создаётся джарник. Всё.
UPD3 Подумал, что нужно уточнить - тестировалось на разных компьютерах.

Клиент:
Главный класс:

```
import java.io.File;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Program started");
    File file = new File("send\\this.txt");
    Sender sender = new Sender();
    sender.Send("Hello world");
    sender.Send("Privet loshara");
    sender.Send(file);
    }
}
```

Собсна, класс сендера в клиенте:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Sender {
    String srvip = "176.195.208.165";
    int srvPort = 7777;
    Socket socket;
    DataOutputStream out;

Sender() {
    try {
        socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(srvip), srvPort);
        System.out.println("Socket created");
        out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        System.out.println("Stream created");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public void Send(File file) {
    try {
        Send("ftn.file");
        Send("this.txt");
        BufferedInputStream fileIn = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file.getPath()));
        System.out.println("FileIn created");
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[8192];
        System.out.println("byteArray created");
        int i;
        i = (int) file.length() / 8192;
        if ((file.length() % 8192) != 0) {
            i++;
        }
        out.writeByte(i);
        out.flush();
        System.out.println("Buffers number sent. Starting file transmission");
        while ((i = fileIn.read(byteArray)) != -1) {
            out.write(byteArray, 0, i);
            System.out.println("Buffer sent");
        }
        fileIn.close();
        out.flush();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
public void Send(String command){
    try {
        byte[] sendBytes = command.getBytes();
        int i = sendBytes.length;
        out.writeByte(i);
        out.flush();
        System.out.println("Command size sent");
        out.write(sendBytes);
        out.flush();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
public void close() {
    try {
        byte[] ftn_stop = ("ftn.stop").getBytes();
        out.write(ftn_stop.length);
        out.flush();
        out.write(ftn_stop, 0, ftn_stop.length);
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
}
```

Сервер:

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int port = 7777;
        int rootCount = 0;
        Socket socket;
        ServerSocket serverSocket;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.print("Waiting for a client... ");
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Client connected");
            DataInputStream in = new     DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            boolean noStopSignal = true;
            while (noStopSignal) {
                System.out.println("Cycle started");
                int commandSize;
                commandSize = in.readByte();
                System.out.println("Got the command size: " + commandSize);
                byte[] commandBytes = new byte[commandSize];
                in.read(commandBytes, 0, commandSize);
                System.out.print("Got the command: ");
                String commandString = new String(commandBytes);
                System.out.println(commandString);
                if (commandString.equals("ftn.file")) {
                    int pathSize = in.readByte();
                    System.out.println("Got the path size: " + pathSize);
                    byte[] pathBytes = new byte[pathSize];
                    in.read(pathBytes, 0, pathSize);
                    System.out.print("Got the path: ");
                    String filePath = new String(pathBytes);
                    System.out.println(filePath);
                    int bufCount = in.readByte();
                    System.out.println(bufCount + " buffers will be     recieved");
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                   File incFile = new File(filePath);
                    incFile.createNewFile();
                    System.out.println("File created");
                    FileOutputStream fileWrite = new     FileOutputStream(incFile);
                    System.out.println("Stream created");
                    int i;
                    System.out.println("Starting recieving");
                    while (bufCount > 0) {
                        i = in.read(buffer);
                        fileWrite.write(buffer, 0, i);
                        bufCount--;
                    }
                    fileWrite.flush();
                    fileWrite.close();
                }
                if (commandString.equals("ftn.stop")) {
                    noStopSignal = false;
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Код хотелось бы видеть как клиентский так и серверный, и каким способом создаете .jar?

Comment: Если не хотите показывать код - то хотя бы напишите, для начала, чем собираете проект. Что используете в проекте(сторонние библиотеки/модули). Возможно в релизе у вас не хватает каких-то билиотек/файлов и т.д. А то вопрос из рода - почему у меня не работает, но я вам ничего не покажу))

Comment: Код показать готов, просто не был уверен, что это нужно. Сейчас прикреплю к основному посту.

Comment: Ну ясен красен у вас относительный путь к файлу, который бьется, запускай вы программу не из той папки.

Comment: Путь сохраняю верный, коннекшн резет выдаёт не на этапе отправки файла, а уже на этапе отправки первой строки.

Comment: Возьмем netbeans(ide такая) во время выполнения из ide компиляция не происходит, а тупо идет подключение по .class(пофайлику) и его исполнение. Отличие от компилированного(оптимизация на лету, медлительнее(всетаки 1 файл проще, но и тама медлительнее джар распаковка работать надо) и то что может вылезти лимит открытых файлов:) Если использовали  нейкие либы надобы их прикрепить, а так не ясно в чем дело.

Comment: Денис, сторонних библиотек не использовал, всё, что использовал - в импорте кода. Представленный в вопросе код - весь код клиента и сервера.

Comment: @ДенисКотляров то есть как компиляция не происходит?

Comment: Неа, это netbeans штучка. Она не компит, не оптимизирует, не складывает это все в jar(для запуска). (оптимизиация налету, компилирует по отдельности .class для запуска).

Comment: Несколько замечаний по коду: 1) раз используете `Data*Stream`, проще передавать строку через `writeUtf`/`readUtf` (они делают, в принципе, то же, что и вы, но лучше, и можно писать меньше кода). 2) `in.read(buffer)` не гарантирует, что массив будет заполнен целиком. Поэтому лучше передавать размер файла, а не число буферов, считать, сколько байт уже принято и делать что-то типа `in.read( buffer, 0, Math.min( filesize - received, buffer.length ) )`. (fixed)

Comment: @zRrr спасибо, учту замечания. writeUTF/readUTF, правда, при тесте не работали даже в IDE. А идею с количеством фрагментов взял из сети, её точно переделаю. Правда, основной проблемы, к сожалению, это не решает.

Comment: у вас два разных jar для клиента и для сервера?
я сделал два разных артефакта и все работает без проблем.